# get coordinates from wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I managed to get my wcf service from http://kailun92wcf.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc, however I need help to consume it and get the xCoord and yCoord to plot it in my map. I managed to get the name but I am stuck at calling out the xCoord and yCoord from wcf service.

```
private void polyc_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var service = new Service1Client();

        service.getRecommendPlaceAsync(new getRecommendPlaceRequest { activityId = 2 }); 
        service.getRecommendPlaceCompleted += new EventHandler<MyCloudService.getRecommendPlaceCompletedEventArgs>(RecommendedPlaceRequestComplete);
    }

    void RecommendedPlaceRequestComplete(object sender, MyCloudService.getRecommendPlaceCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            var result = String.Join(",", (from place in e.Result.getRecommendPlaceResult select place.Name).ToArray());
            MessageBox.Show(result);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + e.Error.Message);
        }

        GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = map.Layers["polyCoords"] as GraphicsLayer;


        foreach (Classes.Places location in data)
        {

            MapPoint point = new MapPoint(Convert.ToDouble(location.XCoord), Convert.ToDouble(location.YCoord));
            mcp.Add(location);
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic graphic = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic() { Geometry = point, Symbol = PolyMarkerSymbol };
            graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of coordinates from the same set of results that you are retrieving your place names from

instead of

```
var result = String.Join(",", (from place in e.Result.getRecommendPlaceResult select place.Name).ToArray());
```

Create a class structure such as

```
public class Points
{
    public decimal XCoordinate { get; set; }
    public decimal YCoordinate { get; set; }
}
```

then have

```
 var coordinates = from place in e.Result.getRecommendPlaceResult select new Points {XCoordinate = place.XCoord, YCoordinate = place.YCoord};
```

coordinates should now have your list.

You are probably just better of having a list of places such as

```
var places = from place in e.Result.getRecommendPlaceResult select place;
```

then you can get any property from the elements in the list

```
foreach (var place in places)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Place: {0} at {1}, {2}", place.Name, place.XCoord, place.YCoord));
            }
```